# Angular [$interpolate:interr] after $http.delete

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I send a DELETE request from the client-side and the server does it's thing server-side and then sends the 'message' back to the client that there's been a successful deletion of a record, Angular is throwing out a weird interpolate error.

Here's my delete function (client-side):

```
$scope.deleteProduct = function () {
    $http.delete('/api/products/product/delete/' + $scope.selectedProduct._id)
    .success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.selectedProduct = {};
        $scope.products = data;
        $scope.tab = 'view-all';
    })
    .error(function (data) {
        console.log('Error deleting product');
    })
};
```

The problem seems to be with the line `$scope.products = data;` and the data auto-refreshing to match the updated records in the database. If I remove this, there are no client-side errors but I have to manually refresh the page to see the updates.

Here's the server-side DELETE:

```
app.delete('/api/products/product/delete/:_id', Auth.ensureAdmin, function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.params);
    products.productsModel.remove({ _id: req.params._id }, function (err, product) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err)
        res.json(product);
        console.log('Deleted product');
    });
});
```

Comment: What does the `console.log(data);` output?

Comment: If data is the id of deleted product then why do you assign this deleted id to products?

Comment: You should remove a product from products where id is equal to the result.

Comment: And I am just curious. You server side is written using Node.js?

Comment: Ah yeah you're right, my mistake. The server is written in Node yes, well, Express.

Comment: I posted this as an answer so you could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the result is returned from the server you get id of the deleted product. So the products should not be assigned to this number. You shoud iterate over products and remove the product that is deleted.